# Hangfire Server start leads to inifite Loop in DI

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

When first navigating to my hangfire dashboard it must start the hangfire server and I end up in an infinite loop between these three scoped services: Repo, ResourceManager and SessionManager. The dependencies between each other are as following:
Repo -> SessionManager
ResourceManager -> Repo & SessionManager

When just starting the application and using swagger these Services are all only called once. However, once I navigate to the hangfire dashboard the constructors of these are called every couple seconds. I am thinking this must be caused by the hangfire server but I have no jobs or schedulers and I even removed all hangfire DBs so they were getting recreated. I am getting confused here. Maybe someone has a clue?

Comment: what I normally do in cases like this is to create test output to either the console or to a file.  The add test output statements to help debug the issue.  This is a chicken and egg problem and until you understand what is occurring first you will never be able to solve issue.  The other thig you can do is to use menu break all.  Then look at the trace stack to find out where the looping started.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to access the call stack to see what's going on but I can't because it is coming from another NuGet Package that I am developing and deploying to my local NuGet Feed. So in the call stack it says [External Code]. As I am using VS Code, I haven't found a simple way to get this to work. However you have another idea on how I can find out why my SessionManagers ctor is called every 2 seconds?

Comment: You added the release version of the NuGet instead of the Debug so you are not seeing the source code from NuGet.

Comment: I can debug the source code but cannot see the call stack

Comment: While code is infinite loop 1) Menu : Debug : Break All 2) Menu : Debug : Windows : Call Stack.